# Assigning a list of numbers binary class in R

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe, classification, binary-data

I'm attempting to transform a list of numbers a binary class based on the below parameters:

IF the value is greater than 3 THEN **0**

IF the value is 3 or less than 3 THEN **1**

Currently I've put together the below if else command. But this is coming back as an error.

```
if (df$DaysOverdue[df$daysoverdue == ">3"]) {
df$DaysOverdue[df$DaysOverdue] <- 0 
}
else {
df$DaysOverdue[df$DaysOverdue] <- 1 
}
```

Comment: Maybe just `df$DaysOverdue <- ifelse(df$DaysOverdue>3,0,1)`. See the `?ifelse` help page. A more [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Doing an exact character match for ">3" seems odd.

Comment: Or maybe `df$DaysOverdue <- as.integer(df$DaysOverdue > 3)`.

Comment: There's a typo in the question, `daysoverdue/DaysOverdue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as easy as this:

```
df$DaysOverdueBin[df$DaysOverdue > 3] <- 0
df$DaysOverdueBin[df$DaysOverdue <= 3] <- 1
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was searching for, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(`Overdue <= 3 Days` = as.numeric(DaysOverdue <= 3))
```